# Make read more button transition smooth

Tags: javascript, html, button, transition, smoothing

I copied some code from w3schools for a read more button but the transition is too quick, how can I make the transition slow and smooth probably with CSS, here's the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp)

Comment: Please show your own code in the post itself.

Comment: Show your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change style of an element from `display: none` to `display: inline`, there's no transition for this case.

you can use visibility and opacity instead of display property + transition:

```
.element {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.element_active {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

if you want to change the size of the element, then use (max-)with or (max-) height + transition:

```
.element {
    max-height: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .element_full-size {
    max-height: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, can I possibly share the code. Or maybe since CSS can't do it we apply JavaScript instead to make the read more text transition or open up smoothly

Comment: function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}

Comment: there are a few properties in css (like display) that cannot be transitioned, they are instant (because they are kinda booleans) and JavaScript cannot change that. so you use either display property or the ones that can have value in between init-value and final-value